# how to transliterate English to Gujarati like google keyboard android

Tags: android, localization, transliteration

Just want to **transliterate** English word to Gujarati word like a lot of keyboard apps already doing it.
For example: When you type "Hello", it gets automatically transliterated to Gujarati word "હેલો" in keyboard suggestions.
Couldn't find it in android documentation.
Tried some workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511512/transliteration-from-hindi-to-english-on-android-without-using-google-api) but it didn't work. 
How to achieve this without third party apis?

PS: I want to transliterate like "**Pay**" to "**પે**"(pronounced as `Pay` also means Pay) Guajarati(Regional language in India) word, not looking for translation which gives a result like "**ચૂકવણી**"(pronounced as `Chukavni` means pay).

Comment: Com'mon! Keyboard apps are already doing it. There is no official docs AFAIK. How do they do?

Answer (score 1):

Google providing API for translation purpose. You can use Translation Client Library to transate English to Gujarati. For more refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java)

Add this gradle to your project

```html
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.85.0'
```

This is the sameple code to translate text.

```html
Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // The text to translate
    String text = "Hello, world!";

    // Translates some text into Russian
    Translation translation =
        translate.translate(
            text,
            TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
            TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ru"));


    System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
    System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", translation.getTranslatedText());
```

Comment: Hey @TakeInfo I want to transliterate like "Pay" to "પે" Guajarati(Regional language in India) word, not looking for translation which gives a result like "ચૂકવણી".

Comment: Google also had transliterate API but it was deprecated see this https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started

Comment: Yes. But how other keyboard apps provide transliterated strings suggestions while typing without internet(Offline), is what I'm looking for. There must be functions/classes in android docs for this functionality. Programatically is there a similar solution like this character mapping ?https://github.com/sanskrit/sanskrit/blob/master/sanskrit/transliterate/sanscript.py

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) and select either the Translation API or AutoML Translation. There is a free user subscription but you can pay to scale accordingly.