# How to transliterate Chinese characters to Zhuyin (in Java)

Tags: java, chinese-locale, transliteration, bopomofo

How to convert Chinese traditional or simplified characters to Zhuyin phonetic notation?

Example

```bash
# simplified
没关系 --> ㄇㄟˊㄍㄨㄢㄒㄧ

# traditional
沒關係 --> ㄇㄟˊㄍㄨㄢㄒㄧ
```

Comment: I have written a detailed answer on this and how you can convert the transliteration from one language to another via hashmap. Have a look, it might help you:). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511512/transliteration-from-hindi-to-english-on-android-without-using-google-api/51557924#51557924

Comment: @Jay: so there is no actual 'algorithm' for this, right? Just need to find an established and verified translation table and that's it, no?

Comment: It's an algorithm, just use hashmap and you are good to go. Takes O(1) time, which technically translates into 1 Microsecond. So yes, it's just writing a proper hash table and use it. You can also use faster technic if you like, and also tell me if you find it. :)

Comment: @NathanHughes: I suppose we should mark them as synonyms. But will need to get enough votes for it: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms. Somebody with enough reputation for the tag can submit the synonym proposal: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bopomofo/synonyms

Comment: @ccpizza: as this is the only question tagged `bopomofo` and you're [the only person](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bopomofo/topusers) who answered a question on this, it will be hard to find someone with more rep on this tag to suggest a synonym ;-)

Comment: for the moment  — yes; but it might change in the future

Answer (score 4):

#### With Python

The [dragonmapper](https://github.com/tsroten/dragonmapper) module does hanzi to zhuyin conversion (internally it converts first to pinyin and then to zhuyin):

```python
# install dependencies: pip install dragonmapper

from dragonmapper import hanzi

hanzi.to_zhuyin('太阳')
>>> 'ㄊㄞˋ ㄧㄤ˙'
```

#### With Java

A possible sequence:

1. convert Chinese text (Simplified or Traditional) to pinyin using [pinyin4j](http://pinyin4j.sourceforge.net/) (java), [pypinyin](https://github.com/mozillazg/python-pinyin) (python), etc.
2. Tokenize the numbered pinyin using a regex created according to this [logic](https://github.com/tsroten/zhon/blob/main/src/zhon/pinyin.py#L82) (*generated [final regex](https://gist.github.com/glowinthedark/6792ed97ac4e813e7870398aad2c70cf)*).
3. Substitute pinyin tokens with zhuyin using documented mappings such as http://www.pinyin.info/romanization/bopomofo/basic.html or [https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~nsw/chinese/pinyin.htm](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/%7Ensw/chinese/pinyin.htm).

#### Possible scenario for step #1:

##### *Java code*

```java
HanyuPinyinOutputFormat outputFormat = new HanyuPinyinOutputFormat();
outputFormat.setToneType(HanyuPinyinToneType.WITH_TONE_NUMBER);
outputFormat.setVCharType(HanyuPinyinVCharType.WITH_U_AND_COLON);
outputFormat.setCaseType(HanyuPinyinCaseType.LOWERCASE);

String[] pinyin = PinyinHelper.toHanyuPinyinStringArray(chineseText, outputFormat);
```

##### *Python code*

```
from pypinyin import pinyin

hanzi_text = '當然可以'
pinyin_text = ' '.join([seg[0] for seg in pinyin(hanzi_text)])
print(pinyin_text)
```

#### Scenario for step #2:

Provided that you generated a list of pinyin segments on step #1 you can now break the pinyin into segments and replace them using a map such as [this one](http://www.pinyin.info/romanization/bopomofo/basic.html) or [this one](https://gist.github.com/glowinthedark/5ea0f92417042ea0a1c43cf05011f9ae) (in js format).

#### Alternative approach

Another solution would be mapping Chinese characters directly to zhuyin using any of the available mappings such as this one: https://github.com/osfans/rime-tool/blob/master/data/y/taiwan.dict.yaml. The downside is that (with this particular source) this will only process Simplified Chinese but won't process Traditional characters.

> ***UPDATE***:
> The mapping from the libchewing project covers both simplified and traditional characters (plus frequency data and special cases for multiple characters): see [word.src](https://github.com/chewing/libchewing/blob/master/data/word.src) (400K) and [tsi.src](https://github.com/chewing/libchewing/blob/master/data/tsi.src) (5.2MB). In order to be able to handle segments you'll probably also want to look for a decent Chinese segmentation library such as [jieba](https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba) (python), [jieba-analysis](https://github.com/huaban/jieba-analysis) (java) etc.